# How to right-align elements in table layout in Java?

Tags: java, android, eclipse, android-tablelayout, android-scrollview

Please have a look at the following XML file

```
<TableLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:id="@+id/tableLayout"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:background="@android:color/white"
    android:stretchColumns="*"
    android:padding="5dp" >

    <TableRow
        android:id="@+id/tableRow0"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content" >

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/textView1"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="Select Words To Remove" />
    </TableRow>

    <TableRow
        android:id="@+id/tableRow2"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_weight="1" >

        <ScrollView 
            android:id="@+id/scrollView"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_span="2"
            android:padding="5dp"

            >


        </ScrollView>
    </TableRow>

    <TableRow
        android:id="@+id/tableRow3"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content" >

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/textView1"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="" />

        <Button 
            android:id="@+id/removeWordsBtn"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="Acerto"
            />
    </TableRow>

</TableLayout>
```

Inside the scrollview of this, I am adding table rows with textviews and buttons dynamically like below

```
ScrollView scrollView = (ScrollView)findViewById(R.id.scrollView);
TableLayout internalTableLayout = new TableLayout(this);


for(int i=0;i<words.size();i++)
        {
            TableRow r = new TableRow(this);
            //r.setId(i);

            TextView t = new TextView(this);


            t.setGravity(Gravity.RIGHT);

            CheckBox c = new CheckBox(this);


            r.addView(t);
            r.addView(c);


            internalTableLayout.addView(r);
        }

        scrollView.addView(internalTableLayout);
}
```

But, what I get is the following

[image]

As you can see, the dynamically generated elements are left aligned. How can I make these right aligned?

Answer (score 0):

### Solution 1:

Use a RelativeLayout, make use of it's attributes:

Replace the children with `android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"` for the `TextView` and `android:layout_alignParentRight="true"` for the `CheckBox.`

That positions the children relative to the parents borders. You may also want to add `android:layout_centerVertical="true" to each child to center the two vertical within each list item.`

### Solution 2:

If you want it for the table,
use `myTable.setColumnStretchable(2, true);` in Java.
and `android:stretchColumns="2" in XML`.

### Solution 3:

Use [CheckedTextView](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/CheckedTextView.html). I think this will serve your need.

Hope that helps.

Comment: Thanks for the reply. But I need to Right Align what I have dynamically generated, not the text view which I have created in XML

Comment: Did you see the Solution 2?

Comment: Yes, that is also not doing well

Comment: Can you try using LinearLayout instead of TableLayout? See if it meets your requirements. It worked for me. Any specific reason for Table Layout?

Comment: I must use ScrollView and I need to add more than 1 element in row. So Linear layout will not work right?

Comment: Will have to check on that. Did not use ScrollView yet. But I think Linear Layout should serve your purpose.

Comment: @Artificial_Intelligence Check Out my edit in Solution 3. This should help you out.